# SwiftUI: How to center a rectangle relative to another view that has a custom anchor scaling effect?

Tags: swiftui

The rectangle should always be centered in ContainerView no matter what scale offset or anchor point innerContainerView has.

What offset is needed to place the rectangle in the center of the ContainerView?

```
let innerContainerSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

struct innerContainerView: View {
    @Binding var ia: [si]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            ForEach(ia) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.green)
                    .scaleEffect(i.scale)
                    .offset(x: i.frame.origin.x, y: i.frame.origin.y)
                    .frame(width: 500 * 0.7, height: 500 * 0.7)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    @Binding var ia: [si]
    @Binding var fscale: CGFloat
    @Binding var foffset: CGSize 
    var body: some View {
        innerContainerView(ia: $ia)
            .frame(width: innerContainerSize.width, height: innerContainerSize.height)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .scaleEffect(fscale, anchor: .init(x: (250 - foffset.width) / 500, y: (250 - foffset.height) / 500))
            .offset(foffset)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ia = [si]()
    @State var fscale: CGFloat = 1
    @State var foffset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            ContainerView(ia: $ia, fscale: $fscale, foffset: $foffset)
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .clipped()
                .offset(x: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add an example?

Comment: what is `si` struct?

Comment: struct si: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let frame: CGRect
    let scale: CGFloat
}

Comment: remove the last offset modifier in ContentView

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.alignmentGuide()` with `GeometryReader`.

Possible example :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let color = [Color.red, .green, .yellow, .blue, .orange, .gray]
    let number = [5,4,3,2,1]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 3, height: 2))
                    .frame(width: 100,height: 100)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 4)
                
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 250,height: 100)
                    .offset(x: 50, y:  75)
                    .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { viewDimension in
                        viewDimension[HorizontalAlignment.center] + 50 // offset of x
                    }
                    .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { viewDimension in
                        viewDimension[VerticalAlignment.center] + 75 // offset of y
                    })
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 4)
                    .position(x: proxy.size.width/2 - 50, y: proxy.size.height/2 - 75)
                // adding this once is enough
                
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 50,height: 30)
                    .offset(x: 100, y: 150)
                    .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { viewDimension in
                        viewDimension[HorizontalAlignment.center] + 100 // offset of x
                    }
                    .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { viewDimension in
                        viewDimension[VerticalAlignment.center] + 150 // offset of y
                    })
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 4)
            }
            .border(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```